# handlebars.js example jquery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

Can you please tell me why this handlebars.js example will not work? I get a jquery error?

***TypeError: e is null in the jquery***

looks like its happening here  `$(document).append(theTemplate(theData));`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/handlebars.js"></script>

    <script type ="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var theData = { headerTitle: 'Shop Page', weekDay: 'Wednesday' };
            var theTemplateScript = $("#header").html();
            var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);
            $(document).append(theTemplate(theData));
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <script id="header" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div> {{ headerTitle }} </div>
        Today is {{weekDay}}
   </script>
   </div>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting here

Comment: try to change the jQuery js file to another version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like the issue was appending to document  if I change it to  body it worked.

```
$('body').append(theTemplate(theData));
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed my jQuery version to 1.7.2 and it fixed the problem.
still not sure what changed in the newer version